# No action on Html.Beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have  `@using (Html.BeginForm())` on a partial view on an application I am developing.  I have a textbox on the page and on clicking the enter button after entering the textbox it is submitting the form.  Is there anyway I can tell MVC not to preform any action in the BeginForm Helper?

I tried passing `@using (Html.BeginForm(null))` but got the same result.  I realise I could probably take out the Html.BeginForm and just use  tags and have javascript return false for the submit action but wondering is there anyway I can achieve this behavior with the html.beginform?

**Update - showing Partial View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 h-form no-padding">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <p>
                <div>

                    <input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                </div>
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update II**
It seems like if there is only 1 text field there and hit enter the form is submitted on POST action.  If I put 2 text fields on the page then hitting either no POST action is invoked.

Anyway I am going to remove Html.BeginForm() and use `<form onsubmit="return false">`

Comment: So you don't want to submit the form?

Comment: So why do you have a form there that you don't want to submit?

Comment: use the form tag to get a handle on all the content that is in the partial view and then serialize that data via ajax to autosave - that is why I could just use form tags but wondering is there another way

Comment: what is the use of form there?Can you elaborate, what actually want

Comment: How you submit your form with java script?

Answer (score 2):

If you want when you click on submit button your form doesn't submit.The submit button type must be **button**

```
<input **type="button"** value="Create" onclick="ajaxSubmit();" />
```

Comment: its a textbox I have on screen though and on hitting enter on it- it is doing a POST

Answer (score 1):

To disable posting the form when hitting enter in a textbox, add the following jquery function:

```
$(function() {
    $(':text').bind('keydown', function(e) { // on keydown event for all textboxes
        if(e.keyCode == 13) { // if key pressed it enter
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <p>
            <div>

                <input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
        </p>
    }
```

and then can perform the task.

or try

```
using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <p>
            <div>

                <input id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
        </p>
    }
```